# In a shared site, how to get products in a category from one site to another?

Tags: categories, images

Our wordpress site(s) is actually 2 in 1. That is, while they are separate host URLs on the same domain, same server, they run from the same set of wp code, but different databases. They are not multisite because a plugin we need was not compatible. Therefore, we are able to give the appearance of separate related sites, and they run on same wp-content/ but different databases.

We're running woocommerce and want to show a set of products in a category from one site, in the other.

So we have `www.domain.com` and `store.domain.com`.  How can we show a category of products in `www` that is configured in `store`?

Thanks in advance, Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not currently running a multi-site install, you can either install the [WP-REST-API plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) which is currently in beta, or you can wait for it to hit core which will probably be around version 4.3 or 4.4.

If you were on a multi-site install, you could have easily used the `switch_to_blog()` function to switch between blog databases to query databases.

WP Rest API Docs : http://wp-api.org/

Evan

Comment: Thanks Evan! DO you know of any plugins or libraries that help  one to use the results of a REST api query and integrate the results with the existing site? IOW, once the queries are pulled, allow the results to be used in existing sites plugins (e.g. sliders)?

Comment: You can parse the results of the response. I believe the results are returned in jSon. If you json_decode() the results, you should be able to store them in an array and then loop over them as you would a standard php array.